# update the table view data from sqlite database in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, uitableview

I insert data in the sqlite database and in the second tab I display the insert data into grouped table view, but the last data I insert doesn't display in the table view, although when I run the app again all data is shown, How I can display all the insert data in the table view??

This my code for select Name and amount from Expense table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSLog(@"sec%i",section);
    NSLog(@"row%i",row);
    NSMutableArray *NAMeA= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
    NSMutableArray *DateA= [NSMutableArray array];
    if (sqlite3_open([[AppDelegate getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql ="select ExpenseMonth,count(*) as day from Expense  where strftime('%m',ExpenseMonth)=strftime('%m','now') group by ExpenseMonth order by ExpenseMonth desc";

        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL);
        if( result== SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *dateAndTime=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
                NSInteger numofday=sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,1);

                MaxEntity *DatTime=[[MaxEntity alloc]initWithDate:dateAndTime andnumofDay:numofday];                
                [DateA addObject:DatTime];
                [NAMeA removeAllObjects];
                NSLog(@"Date %@",dateAndTime);
                NSString *querySQL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Name, amount from Expense  where ExpenseMonth=\"%@\" order by ExpenseMonth desc",dateAndTime];
                const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
                sqlite3_stmt *selectstm = NULL;
                int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &selectstm, NULL);
                if( result== SQLITE_OK) {
                    while(sqlite3_step(selectstm) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                        NSString *NAMe=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstm, 0)];
                        NSString *Amount=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstm, 1)];
                        MaxEntity *NM=[[MaxEntity alloc]initWithName:NAMe andAmount:Amount];
                        [NAMeA addObject:NM];
                        NSLog(@"text%@",NAMe);

                        if ([indexPath section]+1 ==[DateA count] && [indexPath row]+1==[NAMeA count]) {
                            cell.textLabel.text =NM.name;
                            cell.detailTextLabel.text = NM.amountD;
                            NSLog(@"%@ name",NM.name);

                        }
                    }
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(selectstm);
            }
        }else {
            NSLog(@"failed to prepare %d",result);
        }
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Faile to open db");
        sqlite3_close(database);
       [self.table reloadData];

    }
    self.NameArray =NAMeA ;

    self.DateArray = DateA;
       [self.table reloadData];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: select Name and Amount from the table Expense depending on date to display this data in grouped table view in the second tab which I inserted in the first tab..where I should use reloadData?

Comment: i dont understand wt u put here ...please edit it with code write in between ` <code here > `

Comment: In the first tab, after update, you must reload the table from the second tab, or you must refres your table when you click on the second tab.

Comment: I call [self.tableview reloadData];but the new data entered in sqlite didn't loading in the table view

Comment: you are reloading the table.. but are you updating the DataSource also? (NameArray and.. DateArray)?

Comment: How I can update the dataSource and where???

Comment: you just have to run the above code again when you are changing the tab or when you are updating the DB

Comment: Thank u TonyMkenu,  when I move to the second tab for the first time after add new record to the sqlite database in the first tab, the table view update his data, but the second time there is no change on the table view data.

Comment: @FadiaJaradat tell me more .. what you did .. otherwise I have no way to guide you. You put something in viewdidload... or .... what?

Comment: @TonyMkenu In the first tab the user save his Expense and in the second tab all saved expense display in table view, the problem is the table view display this data if I press in the second tab for the first time and when i save data again and return to the second tab there is no updating on the table view, unless run the simulator again, I didn't put any thing in viewdidload, only in cellForRowAtIndexPath as u shown above and in numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView return the array count.

Comment: maybe if i can refresh the tab bar, the table view will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in comments..

to update de table when your tab appear, add in your implementation file of second tab:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       NSLog(@"updateTable");

     [self.table reloadData];
    //or - depend of your your conf
    //[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to reload `UITableView` after Perform `insert/delete/update` Oparation.

```
[self.YourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thank u iPatel, when I use this methode nothing is display in the table view only the titleForHeaderInSection is shown

Comment: The numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView are not updating..How I can update this array count?

Comment: @FadiaJaradat- send ur code to my email ... i will send back to u with solve ur problem :) thanks :)